# CLLocation: Blue current location dot moves unexpectedly

Tags: ios, mapkit, cllocationmanager

This is my code in **`viewDidLoad`**:

```
_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[_locationManager setDelegate:self];
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion hasPrefix:@"8"]) {
    [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
[_locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
[_locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation];

[_locationManager setDistanceFilter:50];
[_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[_locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
```

This is how my `didUpdateLocations` method looks like:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation* newLocation = [locations lastObject];

    CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
    NSDate* eventDate = location.timestamp;
    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (abs(howRecent) < 50.0 && newLocation.horizontalAccuracy > 0) {
        // If the event is recent, do something with it.
        NSLog(@"latitude %+.6f, longitude %+.6f\n",
              location.coordinate.latitude,
              location.coordinate.longitude);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the blue current location dot moves around inaccurately and doesn't stay still.I observe this behavior when I am stationary and not moving around. I am trying to filter the locations in the **`didUpdatelocations`** method but I don't know why it is not working. Please guide me as to how should I go about filtering it. Or do you think this wrong behavior is because of something else?

Comment: How do you add blue dot to the map?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reducing `setDistanceFilter:50`? Per the framework reference, this means that the location only updates after the device has moved 50 meters. The default value is `kCLDistanceFilterNone` to be notified of all movements.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/distanceFilter